# Fastest way of submitting shelved changelist

Tags: perforce

I have shelved a changelist(say X) and I have ensured its correctness. Now i want to submit the changelist. I can

1. p4 unshelve -s X -c Y where Y is a new changelist i create before executing this command.
   Then p4 shelve -c X -d and lastly p4 submit -c Y
2. Otherwise I can unshelve X, delete the shelve X and move the local copies to changelist X(p4 reopen -c X  ) and submit X.
3. The last option is to unshelve X, delete shelve X, p4 change(and edit description) and finally p4 submit

What are your suggestions with regards to :-

1. Use 1/3 but copy paste the description that X already had to new changelists
2. Use 2 but copy each opened file manually in command p4 reopen.

The only advantage of 2 over 1 and 3 is that I don't have to delete X(because it turned out to be my submitted changelist, while in other cases it still is "pending").

Comment: It might be helpful, and allow more users to answer if you could give a description of what the perforce commands are doing in your three scenarios, opposed to just listing them.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The shortest method is:

```
$ p4 shelve -c #changelist -d
$ p4 submit -c #changelist
```

Comment: The first step gives the scary response "Shelved change 111111 deleted." Don't worry, the changelist still exists, and the files are still in it. It's just no longer "shelved".

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 8):

In the new 2013.1 release of the Perforce server, you can now do 'p4 submit -e X', which directly submits the shelf without needing to unshelve it first.

Try it, it's a great feature!

Comment: We still use 12.2. Any ideas for that?

Comment: I'm just going in circles.Submitting change 36629967.
No files to submit.
Cannot submit - files are open by client client-abc at change 36629967.

Answer (score 3):

From my experience with Perforce, I would just unshelve the change-list, delete the shelved files and submit. Just make sure that the description of the change-list is accurate.

Comment: So which one of 1/2/3 are you suggesting?

Comment: 3 sounds the closest to what I described.

Comment: Yours is the only answer that worked for me. Perforce makes this so confusing, in particular from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

With Perforce 2013.1 or later, you can submit the shelved changelist "12345" directly:

```
p4 submit -e 12345
```

On previous versions, use this combination:

```
p4 unshelve -s 12345
p4 submit ...
```

Comment: Submitting change 36629967.
Change 36629967 has shelved files --  cannot submit.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is 2018, here is an updated answer for newer perforce versions (2013.1 and newer)

```
p4 submit -e 123456
```

This command will fail if you already have that shelvelist open in some tree like so:

```
Change 123456 has shelved files --  cannot submit
```

In that case get to the root of that tree (or use `-C client_name_where_shelvelist_is_open`) and revert the changes before running the above command, like so:

```
p4 revert -c 123456 ...
p4 submit -e 123456
```